# Displaying an alert and then redirecting to a specific url in App_Code/BasePage.cs

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a app_code/basepage.cs page. In which I am trying to display an alert message and then redirecting to a page using the following code:

```
if (customerGroupSecuredPage == CustomerGroupSecuredEntity.Project)
    {
       HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script> alert('The Project:'  + entityID + ' exists in ' + (CustomerGroupEnum)CustomerGroupSecuredEntity.Project + '. Please Login to '+ (CustomerGroupEnum)CustomerGroupSecuredEntity.Project); window.location.href='../Project/ProjectList.aspx'</script>");
     }
```

Unfortunately my code is not displaying any alert message and not redirecting to that page. can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use [RegisterStartupScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)